# Setting selected values on MultiSelectList C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, multi-select

I'm working with a simple MultiSelectList on C#.

I just want to populate this MultiSelectList with some string values (not a pair such as <"Key", "Value"> just <"Value">) and set some selected items.

Here's my code:

```
IEnumerable<string> ubicaciones = new string[] { "NEGOCIOS", "TERRITORIOS", 
                                                       "LOCALIDADES" };
IEnumerable<string> ubicacionesSelected = Ubicaciones.Split(',');
UbicacionesPermitidas = new MultiSelectList(ubicaciones, ubicacionesSelected);

IEnumerable<string> transacciones = new string[] { "CARGA: ACCESORIOS", 
                    "CARGA: EQUIPOS", "ASIGNACIONES", "DESINCORPORACIONES", 
                    "PRÉSTAMOS", "TRASLADOS", "SALIDAS" };
IEnumerable<string> transaccionesSelected = Transacciones.Split(',');
TransaccionesPermitidas = new MultiSelectList(transacciones, 
                                  transaccionesSelected);
```

However, is not working... (it shows all the values on the MultiSelectList but it doesn't show any item selected) what am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: "is not working" isn't a very detailed description. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 0):

The values in `Ubicaciones` do not match up with the values in `ubicaciones`. It's the same with `Transacciones` and `transacciones`. If you don't believe that that's the case, please post the code which defines Ubicaciones and Transacciones and we can troubleshoot it further.

Comment: ubicacionesSelected  actually does has matching values with ubicaciones... I'm guessing MultiSelectList doesn't match with string values? does it need a sort of Id for each item?